# Photon Networking Instantiate Error (Unity3d)

Tags: networking, unity-game-engine, instantiation, multiplayer, frame-rate

Ok, so I'm making an online FPS in Unity and I was scripting that Photon Networking Script to connect and spawn the player and I keep getting these two errors:

```
Assets/Resources/GameManager.cs(64,23): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(string, UnityEngine.Vector3, UnityEngine.Quaternion, int)' has some invalid arguments

Assets/Resources/GameManager.cs(64,23): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `UnityEngine.Transform' expression to type `string'
```

Here is where the error is in my code:

```
    // When Connected [Photon Callback]
void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    PhotonNetwork.Instantiate(playerPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, 0);
}

//In Game: Disconnect from room.
void InGameGUI()
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("Leave Game"))
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
}
```

}

And I did reference the Transform at the top:

```
public Transform playerPrefab;
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong and how I could fix it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PhotonNetwork.Instantiate` requires a `string`, not a `Transform` object as it's first parameter. (I do believe this was changed from a `Transform` object a while ago). Simply name the prefab that you want to instantiate (which must be in the `Resources` folder).